# Azure mobile services scheduled job - Are there alternatives to using javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, mobile, azure

Background - 
I am working on a Windows Phone RSS reader app (using C#). In addition to just reading RSS content, the app does some scraping on the articles linked by the feeds to get additional info. This is turning out to be too resource/bandwidth intensive to be done on the client and I am thinking of moving the RSS aggregation and scraping logic to the cloud.

I want to use Azure mobile services. In my simple design, I want to have- 
(1) an Azure DB, which stores all the RSS data including the scraped content.
(2) Front end service which clients can call to get this data
(3) A scheduled task in the cloud that keeps the DB up to date with the latest RSS content. The processing here will be heavy weight since it will scrape thousands of webpages, process them to get additional information, and then update the DB.

*** Actual question ***
My question is regarding (3). I already have C# code that does this on the client and I want to be able to reuse it in developing the scheduled task in the service. I read the Azure mobile services documentation. What they seem to have is a scheduled job which runs javascript. I don't want to use java script and would prefer to reuse my C# code. What is a recommended (and non-hacky) way for me to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Windows Azure WebJobs:
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/

Just create a new (empty) website in Windows Azure, go to the "WEB JOBS" tab and add a new WebJob.

There you can upload your .NET console application which has all your logic (zipped), set a schedule according to your needs and you can use the web sites connection string setting (under the "CONFIGURE" tab) to set your connection string.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I need! Thank you. Are there any caveats I should keep in mind - If I create an Azure mobile service with a SQL Azure DB, then would I create s separate website with a webjob that updates the DB? (PS: I am new to Azure)

Comment: Make sure to use the same connection string, if you use git, it's real easy to deploy your web job by just pushing your repository: http://blog.amitapple.com/post/73574681678/git-deploy-console-app

Answer (score 2):

As of **today**, there isn't any option to run anything but javascript from your Mobile Service.  HOWEVER, if you already have the C# code to perform #3, I would recommend wrapping that in a very light weight Web Service (Web API, etc).  You can host this from Windows Azure Websites.  You can then use the [Windows Azure Scheduler](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Cloud+Cover/Episode-127-Windows-Azure-Scheduler) to schedule a ping of that service which will kick off your job.  You could use the Mobile Services scheduler to ping it as well but using the WA Scheduler would be even easier.

Comment: Thanks. It seems like that would also work for me. The Azure Webjobs approach (in the other reply), however, seems to be more straightforward for my scenario? Please let me know if you have any thoughts.

Comment: Yep, WebJobs will work as well.  I wasn't sure that feature had been released yet but it should be a more straightforward approach than what I've described.